# How To Find A Specific Text in an HTML formatted file

Tags: regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I am working with this URL (http://www.ancient-hebrew.org/m/dictionary/1000.html).

Below is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

raw_html = open('/Users/gansaikhanshur/TESTING/webScraping/1000.html').read()
# lxml is faster. If you don't have it, pip install lxml
html = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'lxml')

# outputs: "http://www.ancient-hebrew.org/files/heb-anc-sm-beyt.jpg"
images = html.find_all('img', src=re.compile('.jpg$'))
for image in images:
    image = re.sub(
        r"..\/..\/", r"http://www.ancient-hebrew.org/", image['src'])
    # print(image)

# outputs: "unicode_hebrew_text"
fonts = html.find_all('font', face="arial", size="+1")
for f in fonts:
    f = f.string.strip()
    print(f)

# outputs: "http://www.ancient-hebrew.org/m/dictionary/audio/998.mp3"
mp3links = html.find_all('a', href=re.compile('.mp3$'))
for mp3 in mp3links:
    mp3 = "http://www.ancient-hebrew.org/m/dictionary/" + \
        mp3['href'].replace("\t", '')
    # print(mp3)
```

I am trying to find the Image files, text files, and audio files. And my code currently finds everything except a text after `</Font>`. For example I am trying to find `e-leph` and `eym` and not sure how to do that.

```
<A Name=    505 ></A>   <IMG SRC="../../files/heb-anc-sm-pey.jpg"><IMG SRC="../../files/heb-anc-sm-lamed.jpg"><IMG SRC="../../files/heb-anc-sm-aleph.jpg">   <Font face="arial" size="+1">  &#1488;&#1462;&#1500;&#1462;&#1507; </Font>     e-leph  <BR>    Thousand    <BR>    Ten times one hundred in amount or number.  <BR>Strong's Number:    505 <BR><A HREF="audio/ 505 .mp3"><IMG SRC="../../files/icon_audio.gif"  width="25" height="25" border="0"></A><BR> <A HREF=../ahlb/aleph.html#505><Font color=A50000><B>AHLB</B></Font></A>    <HR>
    <A Name=    517 ></A>   <IMG SRC="../../files/heb-anc-sm-mem.jpg"><IMG SRC="../../files/heb-anc-sm-aleph.jpg">   <Font face="arial" size="+1">  &#1488;&#1461;&#1501;   </Font>     eym <BR>    Mother  <BR>    A female parent. Maternal tenderness or affection. One who fulfills the role of a mother.   <BR>Strong's Number:    517 <BR><A HREF="audio/ 517 .mp3"><IMG SRC="../../files/icon_audio.gif"  width="25" height="25" border="0"></A><BR> <A HREF=../ahlb/aleph.html#517><Font color=A50000><B>AHLB</B></Font></A>    <HR>
```

So in the end I would like to find all words that come after the unicode such as `e-leph` and `eym`

Answer (score 1):

If our desired outputs are all similar to the example listed in the question, we can for instance define a char class `([\w-])`, add any chars that we like to collect, then use `<\/font>` as a left boundary and `<br>` as a right boundary. We would also add groups with optional spaces and our expression would look like:

```
<\/font>(\s+)?([\w-]+?)(\s+)?<
```

or

```
<\/font>(\s+)?([\w-]+?)(\s+)?<br>
```

with an `i` flag.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Dqu9fo/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"<\/font>(\s+)?([\w-]+?)(\s+)?<"

test_str = ("<A Name=    505 ></A>   <IMG SRC=\"../../files/heb-anc-sm-pey.jpg\"><IMG SRC=\"../../files/heb-anc-sm-lamed.jpg\"><IMG SRC=\"../../files/heb-anc-sm-aleph.jpg\">   <Font face=\"arial\" size=\"+1\">  &#1488;&#1462;&#1500;&#1462;&#1507; </Font>     e-leph  <BR>    Thousand    <BR>    Ten times one hundred in amount or number.  <BR>Strong's Number:    505 <BR><A HREF=\"audio/ 505 .mp3\"><IMG SRC=\"../../files/icon_audio.gif\"  width=\"25\" height=\"25\" border=\"0\"></A><BR> <A HREF=../ahlb/aleph.html#505><Font color=A50000><B>AHLB</B></Font></A>    <HR>\n"
    "    <A Name=    517 ></A>   <IMG SRC=\"../../files/heb-anc-sm-mem.jpg\"><IMG SRC=\"../../files/heb-anc-sm-aleph.jpg\">   <Font face=\"arial\" size=\"+1\">  &#1488;&#1461;&#1501;   </Font>     eym <BR>    Mother  <BR>    A female parent. Maternal tenderness or affection. One who fulfills the role of a mother.   <BR>Strong's Number:    517 <BR><A HREF=\"audio/ 517 .mp3\"><IMG SRC=\"../../files/icon_audio.gif\"  width=\"25\" height=\"25\" border=\"0\"></A><BR> <A HREF=../ahlb/aleph.html#517><Font color=A50000><B>AHLB</B></Font></A>    <HR>\n")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired or you wish to modify it, please visit [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gtYXJc/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex. Use next_sibling and the css selector shown below.

You have the pattern of glyphs then font tag then word

[image]

Use the `adjacent sibling` combinator, `+`, to get the `font` tag sibling following immediately after `img` tag as highlighted in image above. Then `next_sibling` will take you to the word.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('http://www.ancient-hebrew.org/m/dictionary/1000.html')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
words = [item.next_sibling.strip() for item in soup.select('img + font')]
```

Sample of output:

[image]

Comment: Did you try this?